# This Ban command does not work... How can I fix it?

Tags: discord.py

Here is my ban command! Everytime I want to ban someone it dosen't go thru else! To be honest it dosen't do anything other than the if! Please help!

```
@bot.command() #ban (verified works)
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    if member == ctx.author or member.id == bot.user.id:
        await ctx.send("Unfortunatly I cannot do that!")
        return
    else:
        await ctx.send('Banned the member {}'.format(ctx.member.mention))
        await member.ban(reason = reason)
        await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: Debug your code on the `if` line and check why it is 'stuck' on this condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend not using the role to check if the user can use the command, rather try using something like this:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member,*,reason=None):
    try:
        await member.ban(reason=reason)
        embed = discord.Embed(description=f":white_check_mark: succesfully banned {member.mention}!",color=0x00ced1)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    except:
        e2 = discord.Embed(description="You don't have permission to use this command",color=0xff0000)
        await ctx.send(embed=e2)
```

This allows you to use the bot in multiple servers, who don't necessarily have the same roles, and also narrows it down to a certain permission.